# Create image fonts for android

Tags: android, fonts

I would like to create my own fonts from icons/images to use in my android app development.

I tried to find solution on Google but no luck..

1. do you know if it possible to create colorful fonts from images for Android?
2. if so how I can do it and which fonts file type support color and android?

Thanks

Comment: TTF is supported in android

Comment: Did you make any progress on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Google have proposed [a new color bitmap specification](https://color-emoji.googlecode.com/git/specification/v1.html) (intended to support color emoji). If [this report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324187) has merit, the new format is supported under Android KitKat. You may be able to use the tools from the [color-emoji](https://code.google.com/p/color-emoji/) project to create fonts in this format.